# How to Integrate Office 365 with ionic2 (Cordova) application?

Tags: cordova, ionic2, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I want to do **Office 365 Integration with ionic2 (Cordova) application** which will do following task.

How to Use Outlook client object to access O365 services like mail, calendar and contact?

Please let me know if anyone knows it.

Comment: Edited to restrict the question.